# Swap views between 2 fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

In my app I have 3 fragments all of the same type but the views are modified based on data. so i have FragmentA, FragmentB, and FragmentC (all the same type) and initially FragmentA has View1, FragmentB has View2, fragmentC has View3. After swiping to the side, I want View2 moved to FragmentA, View3 moved to FragmentB, and a new view created for FragmentC.

What is the best way to do this? I know I could replace FragmentC with a new fragment that creates its own view, then replace FragmentB with FragmentC, then replace FragmentA with FragmentB but that seems like a lot of overhead when all i want is to update the views inside the fragments.

Comment: Why are you trying to replace the views instead of using FragmentPagerAdapter? I also know I used a 3rd party library to limit the tabs at the top to 3 but why don't you just use that?

Comment: I would, but the number of fragments is unlimited. I don't like the idea of just using 1000 or some high number for the itemCount so I have the count set to 3 so you can swipe left and right 1 space and after swiping left or right it will bring you back to the middle fragment and update it's view so it looks like the fragment you just swiped to.

Comment: Well again you could use a view pagger then on the right swype replace the fragment in the middle one and programatically send you back one tab in the viewpagger. Also you can have it start on tab 1 ([0,1,2]) then check out ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.

Comment: That's what i'm doing. And you can't use OnPageChangeListener that makes it look glitchy. You have to use the OnPageScrollStateChanged and check what the current item is when the state is idle. I'm asking how to switch the views so when you swipe to the left you see fragment 3 and then i need to switch it back to fragment 2 and move fragment3's view into fragment2.